# Why are the shear stresses corresponding to adjacent faces of the stress element equal?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

I am studying the definition of the stress element from the book Theory of Elasticity from S. Timoshenko and J.N Goodier. In page 3 it is shown that from taking the moment of forces acting on the element along the x-axis (which must be zero to be in equilibrium), body forces are neglected compared to the surface forces caused by the stresses, since the the body forces reduce as the cube of linear dimensions and surface forces to the square, resulting the body forces to be small quantities of higher order compared to surface forces. I undertand this because body forces are forces per unit of volume which depends on the cube of linear dimentions compared to the surface forces which are forces per unit of area.

What I do not understand is what follows from that. The book states that: "Similarly, moments due to nonuniformity of distribution of normal forces are of higher order than those due to the shearing forces and vanish in the limit."

First of all. What does "nonuniformity of distribution of normal forces" mean in this context? Why are these of higher order than the moments due to shear forces?

After these considerations calculations are made but some shear forces are left out. I will upload an image to be more clear:[image][image]

From figure 3, $\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{xz}$ are not considered, why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

> What does "nonuniformity of distribution of normal forces" mean in this context?

It means that the element is small enough that there's no variation in $\sigma_{ii}$ over the face with normal unit vector $i$. That is, since $dy$ and $dz$ are small, $\frac{d\sigma_{xx}}{dy}dy$ and $\frac{d\sigma_{xx}}{dz}dz$ (higher order than $\tau_{ij}$) are assumed to be negligible, for example.

> From figure 3, τxy
> and τxz
> are not considered, why would that be?

The element is assumed to be motionless, so $\tau_{xy}=\tau_{yx}=\tau_{xz}=\tau_{zx}$. If this weren't the case, the element would begin to translate and rotate from the nonzero net force and moment:

[image]  

[image]

In addition, a load perpendicular to an axis does not produce a moment around that axis.

Comment: The author wants to prove that in a general case of stresses applied to a stress element: τxy=τyx, τxz=τzx, τyz=τzy. For that, he first neglects body forces, then forces by normal stresses. Only shear stresses are left to take moment along the x-axis. But when he does, he does not calculate the moments due to τxy and τxz, which according to me should be taken into account. My question is why is that. Regarding my other question, I understand that the variation of the normal stresses can be neglected, but why are the moments of these neglected with respect to those of shear stresses.